# Changes to language for not unicode programs in Windows 10 not applied

Tags: windows-10, language, locale

I'm trying to change the Language for non unicode programs in Windows 10.

I tried these steps:

Region -> Administrative -> Language for non-unicode programs -> Change system locale -> Select language

After selecting the language I'm prompted to restart the computer, but after restart I still see the old settings.

*Note: The language pack for the selected language is installed.*

How to change this setting ?

Comment: Does this happen if you boot instead into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode) ?

Comment: Tried to restart in Safe Mode, but there is no Region menu here at all

Comment: There must be one in Control Panel.

Comment: @harrymc , When I start windows normally there is a Region menu at path "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region", but when in Safe mode I see only "Date and Time" and "Language". If I search in Control Panel "Region" I also get no results.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700488/806867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several locales for the same language in the dropdown selection. Any of them are shown as installed and work when I add them as languages, but some of them are not applied when changing the language for non unicode programs.

I think maybe the language packs are incomplete for some language locales.

After trying the other language locale the changes as described in the question work with no problems. The behavior is not intuitive so, hope this answer helps someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar situation with docker image installed with different regional settings. It was changing non-unicode language back to dockers images language.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).